# Update a Python list

Tags: python, list

I was trying to update a list which contents a few lists. When I try to update a one element of a list within the list it seems updating all lists of the list. But it only happens when I create the list in the following way. I have no clue why this is the case.

```
example_list = [[0,0]]*3
print(example_list)

example_list[0][0] = 1
print(example_list)
print('')

example_list = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
print(example_list)

example_list[0][0] = 1
print(example_list)
```

==========================================

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]

[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: https://pythonplotscience.blogspot.in/2017/08/update-python-list-dont-know-why-this.html

Comment: Now let us consider the following...

Comment: example_list = [0]*3
print(example_list)
example_list[0] = 2
print(example_list)